# code to set a select box option value as an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml, dhtml

in an html page i have got, i have a select box like this with values.

```
<select onChange="return filler(this.value);">
<option value="{'name':'rajiv',age:'40'}">a</option>
<option value="{'name':'mithun',age:'22'}">f</option>
</select>
```

i want to pass a javascript array or object as the option value.
right now it is treating the option value as a string.

i want it to be an array so that i can access it by

this.value.name,this.value.age in the filler function.

is this possible?

Comment: how to get data from select using java?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You will not be able to store objects/arrays in the `value` attribute, however an option would be to use `data-*` attributes which supports json automatically with jQuery 1.4.3+

```
<select>
    <option data-value='{"name":"rajiv","age":"40"}'>a</option>
    <option data-value='{"name":"mithun","age":"22"}'>f</option>
</select>
```

And using `.change()`

```
$("select").change(function(){
    alert($(this).find(":selected").data("value").age);
});
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/qz4pC/)**

Comment: Passing a string and then converting it into JSON might ease the work... [Answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23405277/2260614)

Answer (score 16):

No, not just like that. Values have to be strings. I'd strongly recommend to use something like jQuerys `.data()` method to hold `Arrays` or `Objects` in an expando property.

If it must be in the value, you just need to JSON decode (.parse) it:

```
var myValue = JSON.parse(this.value);

myValue.age; // 40
myValue.name // rajiv
```

But again, I don't think this is a good solution. Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/
Also, jQuery will automatically convert Arrays and Objects if you put the JSON strings in any `data-` HTML5 attribute. For instance:

```
<option value="A" data-info="{'name':'rajiv',age:'40'}">something</option>
```

If you access that node with jQuery now, we automatically got that object in it's data expando

```
$('option').data('info').name; // === rajiv
```

Comment: could you expand on why using `JSON.parse()` isn't a good solution?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to convert the string to an object when using it, but the value needs to be a string.

```
  var option = $('select').val();
  var selected = $.parseJSON(option);
  alert( selected.name + ': ' + selected.age );
```

Comment: ...and it would need to be made into valid JSON.

Answer (score 2):

**React solution**

```
const myObjects = [
    {
        text: 'a',
        value: 1
    },
    {
        text: 'b',
        value: 2
    },
];

const handleSelectChange = (myStringifyObject) => {
    const myObject = JSON.parse(myStringifyObject);
    // logic with myObject
} 

<input type='select' onChange={(evt) => handleSelectChange(evt.target.value)}>
    {myObjects.map((myObject) => (
        <option
            value={JSON.stringify(myObject)}
            key={myObject.value}
        >
            {myObject.text}
        </option>
     ))}
</input>
```

Comment: What if i have about 5000 options in my select box, I have to convert each of these?