# jquery multi select transfer with data options

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, multi-select, html-select

I created a many to many multi select box with a left and right pane, conform [this example](http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/easy-multi-select-transfer-with-jquery.html). This all works fine if the option value is simple. Now I want to store an object in the option's value attribute. As the value option only accepts strings, one has to use the `$.data('key', 'value')`  to bind the value to the option [(see here for SO ref)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572553/code-to-set-a-select-box-option-value-as-an-object). When I want to transfer the select area from left to right with:

```
$('#left-pane option:selected').remove().appendTo('#right-pane');
```

the data-value doesn't get transfered. Is there a way to easily transfer the option with the data-value attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) , to preserve all jQuery data associated with the element, like so:

```
$('#left-pane option:selected').detach().appendTo('#right-pane');
```