# Access values in select option tag with more than one value using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDiv(divID,val) {
        var text= val.value;
        alert(text);
    }
</script>

Mouse:<select onChange="showDiv('#mouse',this);">
    <option value="">Select Mouse Type</option>
    <option value="{'text':'Normal','id':'normalMouse'}">Normal</option>
    <option value="{'text':'Gaming','id':'gamingMouse'}">Gaming</option>
</select>
```

The output is:

> {'text':'Normal','id':'normalMouse'}

But The output should be 'normal' only. That means I want to access to those values separately.How to do that?

Comment: `text = JSON.parse(text); alert(text.text);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [w3c org option](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/option) doc's value can have only string value so it is necessary to convert it into object..

---

<kbd>***[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGY69/)***</kbd>
***Javascript code***

```
function showDiv(divID, val) {
    var value = eval('(' + val.value + ')');
    alert('Text: "' + value['text'] + '" Id: "' + value['id'] + '"');
}
```

---

As @Johan say's using `eval()` is not a safe method.. So for the scenarios where safety is even concerned <kbd>[Working Fiddle using JSON.parse](http://jsfiddle.net/NGY69/1/)</kbd>

***HTML***

```
<option value='{"text":"Normal","id":"normalMouse"}'>Normal</option>
<option value='{"text":"Gaming","id":"gamingMouse"}'>Gaming</option>
```

***Javascript***

```
function showDiv(divID, val) {
    var value = JSON.parse(val.value);
    alert('Text: "' + value['text'] + '" Id: "' + value['id'] + '"');
}
```

---

Hope it helps..!!

Comment: Never use `eval()` to parse JSON. In fact, don't use it at all. What if the user inject whatever javascript code he prefers to the attribute and triggers the event?

Comment: @bhavik you gave me the perfect answer. thanks a lot

Comment: @johan yes thats true. but I just wanted to demonstrate this only. So both of you gave me the correct answer. I dont consider security at all here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're saving an object in string format, how about parsing it first:

```
var o = JSON.parse(val.value);
console.log(o.text, o.id);
```

Though single quotes aren't valid for JSON keys nor properties, so I'd suggest that you store your extra data with the valid html5 `data` attribute e.g.

```
<option value="something" data-text="Normal" data-id="normalMouse">
    Normal
</option>
```

And access it using

```
var text = val.getAttribute('data-text'); // etc...
```

Comment: Or he can do `JSON.parse(val.value.replace(/'/g,'"'))`

Comment: @BatuZet True, allthough I prefer the latter example. If he wants to store complex objects associated with an element, jQuery's `data` method is the way to go, IMO.

Comment: @johan Thank you for the answer. I'll try it now and get back to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Convert `'` to `"`, and then parse it to Json Format

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showDiv(divID, val) {
    var text        = val.value,
        // convert ' to "
        jsonStrText = text.replace(/'/g, '"'),
        // parse to json
        jsonText    = JSON.parse(jsonStrText);

    alert(jsonText.text);
}
</script>
```

---

Or you can modify html to

```
<option value="{\"text\":\"Normal\",\"id\":\"normalMouse\"}">Normal</option>
```

And Directly parse to Json Format

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showDiv(divID, val) {
    var text        = val.value,
        // directly parse to json
        jsonText    = JSON.parse(text);

    alert(jsonText.text);
}
</script>
```