# how to append dropdown option value as an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

My json looks like this.I need to append name as key and data as value in dropdown option .

```
   {
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "name1",
    "Year" : 2018,
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "day" : 1.0,
            "count" : 34.0,
            "month" : "May",
            "price" : 1.0,
            "amount" : 51.0
        }, 
        {
            "day" : 2.0,
            "count" : 34.0,
            "month" : "May ",
            "price_typ" : 1.0,
            "amount" : 51.5
        }, 
        {
            "day" : 3.0,
            "count" : 34.0,
            "month" : "May",
            "price_typ" : 1.0,
            "amount" : 50.0
        }, 
        {
            "day" : 4.0,
            "count" : 34.0,
            "month" : "May",
            "price_typ" : 1.0,
            "amount" : 51.0
        }, 
        {
            "day" : 5.0,
            "count" : 34.0,
            "month" : "May",
            "price_typ" : 1.0,
            "amount" : 51.0
        }
    ]
}
```

In my code i append name as key and data as option value but am getting [object,object] instead of array values.

```
for(var j=0;j<result.length;j++){
$("#custom-dropdown").append(
"<option value="+result[j].data+">"
+ result[j].name
+ "</option>");  
}
```

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572553/code-to-set-a-select-box-option-value-as-an-object). The question is kind of similar. Please refer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not do `"<option value="+result[j].data+">"` since you are telling JS to `unbox` result[j].data as a string and since that is an object JS would tell you that it is `[object, object]`

Simple test:

```
var a = {}; 
a.toString() // returns "[object Object]"
```

Which part/property value from `data` do you need as value?

Comment: Is it possible to add full data as in option value ?

Comment: I guess you could add it as a string version of that object via `JSON.stringify` and then when you handle the selection you can transform back to object via `JSON.parse` ... but this is not a very good and elegant way to do this.